# Create Association on Registration Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I currently have 3 models set up:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user_type, polymorphic: true

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable, :rememberable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user, as: :user_type
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user, as: :user_type
end
```

I would like to know what the best way to, upon a user signing up, create either a Student or Teacher, that is automatically associated to the User.

The Student & Teacher models have different attributes, but a User must be either one or the other.

My initial thought was to do the registration through the Student/Teacher Model, and then call devise's create method within the Student/Teacher create method, although I'm not entirely sure how to do that as well.

As an aside, one this is set up correctly, how would I go about setting different redirect paths after sign in depending on whether the user is a Student or a Teacher?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the condition for it to be student or teacher, but you could do that on "before_create" callback.
For example, something like this on user model:

```
before_create :assign_role

def assign_role
//if condition, teacher.create or student.create
end
```

But have you considered to use inheritance, instead? Put User as superclass of student and teacher, and on then, instead of

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
```

it would be

```
class Teacher < User
```

then on teacher/student model you would put the particular attributes and methods you want. I think it's more clean and ellegant. Good luck!